# Jaax-jquery Estado "procesando" para barra Pace.js

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy usando pace.js (que es como la barrita de carga superior de youtube) para la barra de carga en mi página web, y para que detecte las peticiones de ajax utilizo :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { Pace.restart(); });
```

Lo cual ejecuta la barra de pace cuando inicia la petición pero pues obviamente ele vento Start demora menos que lo que dura procesando la petición y hace que se anime la barra pero la animación acaba  antes de que la petición se ejecute completamente.

tal vez no conoscan pace, entonces mi pregunta también puede ser, ¿que evento capturo para que la animación concuerde con la duración total de la petición de Ajax de jquery?, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la respuesta, la dejo por si alguien tiene la misma duda

Hay que encerrar el ajax en `Pace.track`, de esta forma:

```
Pace.track(function() {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      "data": formData
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/sendmail.php",
    success: function(data) {
      //succes
    }
  });
});
```